# Column Values are empty when filling datatable using data adapter

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, datatable, dataadapter

I have a strange behaviour happening in my data adapter filling method. Im calling a stored procedure which returns a result set. but when using data adapter fill method some column values seems missing/gone empty. Its a strange behaviour and i could see the result set in sql server with above mentioned procedure. By the way, Its not a typed dataset/Datatable which i'm filling to. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please close this question as my code was bit wrong from my side and did not happend when coded correctly. thanks for viewing..